# Android Material LinearProgressIndicator is not repeating

Tags: android, material-components-android

After calling `show` on a `LinearProgressIndicator` the indicator progresses to the end once and then hides.

From everything I've found it should keep repeating until I hide it.

I declare it like

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/busyIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/map_view"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:indicatorColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        />
```

And then hide and show it like

```kotlin
if (busy) {
    binding.content.busyIndicator.show()
} else {
    binding.content.busyIndicator.hide()
}
```

I've tried removing the call to `hide` but it still gets hidden.
I get the same behavior with `CirclularProgressIndicator`.

I've tested with versions 1.3.0 and 1.4.0-alpha02

I've I change the XML to have it start out visible and then never call `hide` or `show`, then it correctly repeats.

Is there a function I'm missing?
Should I not be using `show`?

Comment: might be a silly question but are there any other areas where `show()` and `hide()` are called?

Comment: No, those two calls are the only interaction with the indicator.